# Server unexpectedly closed network connection after setfacl Putty

Tags: ssh, ftp, file-permissions

I'm newbie, I created a new user and disabled root and everything works well. I want to edit `sshd_config` in `/etc/ssh directory` with FileZilla but I don't have the right so I tought that I need to give my user permission to edit.

In `/etc/ssh` so I run this command on putty:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:myuser:rwx /etc/ssh
```

Just after that when I want to login with putty or FileZilla I get:

> Server unexpectedly closed network connection

I can't anymore connect to my server via ssh. What's the solution to this problem please?

Comment: You probably need an alternate access not requiring ssh, like remote console, to repair the damages.

Comment: I have alternate access not requiring ssh, but what should I do to repair the damages that's the question

Answer (score 2):

The daemon handling SSH, which stands for *Secure* Shell, takes security very seriously. In particular it considers as an anomaly to have a *private* host key file readable or writable by an other user than root, and it will refuse to use such key (you can probably see this in your logs). If all keys are in this state, as was done with your command, *sshd* will simply give up when a connection is attempted, because at least one host key is needed.

So since you have an alternate access, it's simple: use it to completely remove all the additional ACLs you added with this command:

```
sudo setfacl -R -b /etc/ssh
```

with `-b` removing all extended ACLs and leaving only the original base Unix (or Linux) ACLs: user,group,other as they were before.

You should probably not attempt to edit with Filezilla the configuration file, but stick to a shell access: copy it elsewhere, edit elsewhere (with Filezilla if you wish), and use an SSH shell to actually replace it (and reload the daemon).

Last advice: when tinkering with a remote access, always keep such a remote access connected. Don't disconnect and reconnect from it to test it, but instead attempt to connect *a second time*. If it fails you know you made something wrong and should revert ASAP whatever it was, which is possible with the remaining connected access. Even this isn't failsave if you are disconnected because of an unrelated reason. Anyway you also have an alternate access which is good.

Comment: the problem is resolved with another way but this command seems to be useful and thanks so much for the advice and for all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I give SSH folder 0700 permission and files on it 0600 permissions and the problem is resolved.

I didn't try the: sudo setfacl -R -b /etc/ssh
because the problem is resolved but it seems that's a good solution.
Thanks so much